# java xml with invalid character

Tags: java, xml

i have tag

with value *ÀÀ 5ÀÀ in my xml data which is use object conversion for the pojo class.
but am getting the below error
An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x14) was found in the element content of the document. Any suggetion how to remove the invalid character.

Comment: would recommend that you put in a sample xml similar to what you have so that its easier to figure out the problem. Maybe even the code that you use to load up the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to start of your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

If your xml is not created with utf-8 encoding get a text editor like notepad++ to have the encoding as utf-8. (This option is in the taskbar as encoding)

Also, all characters below 0x20 is disallowed, except 0x9 (TAB), 0xA (CR?), 0xD (LF?)

If you are interested in only removing the invalid characters you can use this :
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/removing-invalid-characters-from-xml-backups-12079.html

Comment: Yes i added that too but it doesn't solve the issue. because the latin character are fetched by the xml at particular tag

Comment: try the utility mentioned in link it should do the thing. :-)